# Bar series not rendering correctly under label using the react-vis library

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-vis

I'm running into a problem. The bar series is not coming right under it's label. I can't figure out what is going wrong.

[image]

Here is the code for it

```
const FlexibleXYPlot = makeWidthFlexible(XYPlot);


<FlexibleXYPlot height={graphContainer.height} margin={graphContainer.margin} xDistance={0} xType="ordinal">
        <HorizontalGridLines />
        <XAxis/>
        <YAxis orientation="right" style={yAxisStyles} />
        {  this.state.data.map((lineData, i) => (
      <VerticalBarSeries
        key={i}
        data={lineData.timeline}
      />
    )); }
      </FlexibleXYPlot>
```

and the data is this

```
[
    {
      "timeline": [
        {
          "x": "dataA",
          "y": 12.21
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "timeline": [
        {
          "x": "dataB",
          "y": 21.09
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "timeline": [
        {
          "x": "dataC",
          "y": 16.66
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: please attach your style

Comment: Hi @Alex, I'm using react-vis styles. I've figured out the problem. It's because for each bar I'm rendering a separate series which is causing the issue. I've fixed that but because of it another issue popped up and that is, now I can't render each bar with different color. Any idea on how can I achieve it

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your issue, do you have any sandbox?

Comment: @Alex here is the url https://codesandbox.io/s/react-vis-zoom-nkl8b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @Alex, thanks for your time. I've figured it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

For each bar I was creating a separate series. I just had to pass the whole data to a single series. Now if somebody wants each bar to have a different color in a single series they can pass the color with the data like given below

```
[
    {
          "x": "dataA",
          "y": 12.21,
          "color": <something>
    },
    {

          "x": "dataB",
          "y": 21.09,
          "color": <something>
    },
    {
          "x": "dataC",
          "y": 16.66,
          "color": <something>
    }
]
```

and we need to pass `colorType="literal"` to the series itself.

Comment: Exactly!https://github.com/uber/react-vis/blob/master/docs/colors.md